Filtering on MVT layers
I'm looking to serve MVT layers from GeoServer using a PostGIS data store.
I was hoping to use a condition in the SQL view and provide viewparams to limit what data is served.
I think this is not possible, and that MVT layers will not use viewparams. Can anyone confirm this?

Why do you think that? What exactly have you tried? Does your layer work for other output formats?  What does the log file show after you turn logging up to GeoTools developer?

I have tried sending requests to a query which takes in an argument. I set the default. When I pass the param I expected it to be, it does not override the default.
Are you saying MVT layers will respect viewparams?
